How do rich people not pay inheritance taxes?
For example, Laurene Jobs inherited 5.5 million apple shares when her husband died in 2011 at $400 a share. She also inherited 7.3% of disney which was $67b market cap or $5b. The total value was $7 billion.
Since then the Disney part has grown to over $10b and the apple part $40b for a total implied net worth of $50b plus a few percent for dividends. We know from public filings she didn't own anything else for a significant length of time.
You would expect from a capital gains tax on the sale of the inheritance plus the inheritance tax itself that 90% of this would be taxed and $5b at most would be left. In reality her net worth is listed as $15 billion.
Likewise Sam Walton died with $9b and share growth would put that as $200b now. However, Rob, Jim and Alice Walton today have over $200 billion.
How come the inherited net worth of billionaires is the same as if they didn't pay taxes at all? Are they doing something to not pay inheritance taxes or do the trusts have some kind of tax concession that is being counted as net worth?
It should also be in theory impossible to just borrow X amount against the stock and use that for the tax because the estate tax is charged on all assets- i.e., anything you borrow to pay the tax is also an asset and gets taxed.

Steve Jobs had no daughter named "Lauren". I believe you most likely meant his wife Laurene. His children's names are Lisa, Reed, Erin, and Eve.

Also, if his wife was intended, I think that may make a rather huge difference, considering they resided in California, which has Community Property laws for spouses.

Short Answer

How come the inherited net worth of billionaires is the same as if
they didn't pay taxes at all?

Capital gains accrued at death are tax free. And, there are relatively easy ways to avoid triggering them (some of which were the subject of considerable debate in the 2024 Presidential election).
Billionaires do pay significant taxes at death (about $17 billion a year, collectively), but they can and do meaningfully reduce those tax bills with good planning almost all of the time. Billionaires who avoid paying any taxes do so by giving most of their wealth to private charitable foundations at death (many famous billionaires have them in their estate plan, e.g. Bill Gates, the CEO of Microsoft).
The reality that a lot of a very wealthy person's wealth will go to taxes or charity also encourages rather extravagant spending during life (trips to space, fancy yachts, expensive jewels and art, many expensive mansions and palaces, etc.), although there is quite a bit of dispute among economists about how strong of an effect this is.
The more estate planning and tax planning a family does before they get really, really rich (in cases where they ultimate do get really, really rich), the easier it is to reduce lifetime transfer tax and income tax burdens.
Long Answer
There are lots and lots of ways of doing this. I practice law in this area and have done so since 1996, wtih this being my primary area of practice (and teaching) for several of those years, including some time as an associate professor of estate planning in a master's degree program. I don't cite chapter and verse of the relevant tax law authorities as this would make the answer 50% longer and it would take three times as long to write it.
There are two main taxes that have to be optimized, although state level or foreign taxes are sometimes also relevant to U.S. taxpayers.

Income taxes (mostly taxes on capital gains and taxes on "income in respect of a decedent", the dominant form of which consists of income taxes on distributions inherited retirement accounts).

Transfer taxes (during life, the gift tax, at death, the estate tax, and in both cases, the generation skipping transfer tax).


In addition, in some U.S. states, the probate process is very expensive and cumbersome and lawyers help clients to avoid it. (In other states, like Colorado, probate is cheap, fast, private, and lax and it makes little sense to try to avoid it.)
All of those approaches to reducing income tax and transfer tax burdens are 100% legal and probably 90%-95% of affluent people use some of them. All facts are fully disclosed to the IRS which signs off on it. The audit rate for estate tax returns (IRS Form 706) is about 50%, which is higher than any other kind of tax return, even the income tax returns of large publicly held corporations.
Income Tax Planning
In the case of capital gains taxes, all accrued capital gains in assets that are not realized as of the date of death of the owner of the assets, are income tax free. The beneficiary is treated as having purchased those assets for fair market value on the date of death (subject to some minor loophole closing tweaks). But assets given as a gift during life to an individual or trust take a carry over basis (which means that they are treated for capital gains tax purposes as if they were purchased, improved, and depreciated in the same way that the donor did).
There are also a few ways to defer capital gains taxes, the most widely used of which is a 1031 exchange (named after the relevant tax code section) which allows someone selling investment real estate to trade it for other investment real estate without triggering capital gains taxes (this also has a "carry over basis").
Capital gains on other assets can be deferred by borrowing against appreciated assets, rather than selling them (often with margin loans or just unsecured lines of credit extended due to a borrower's strong balance sheet), in order to avoid triggering capital gains taxation during life (knowing that if one waits until death, it is forgiven).
Income taxes on income in respect of a decedent are minimized by preferentially giving those assets to people in low tax brackets, and by paying them out over as long a time period as possible.
Other notable strategies for reducing income taxation involve the use of whole life insurance (whose build up of cash value and death benefit are usually tax free), investing in municipal bonds (whose interest payments are usually tax free), and using large investment or operating losses from business and investing to offset against income from profitable investments or businesses.
For the high end of middle class to upper middle class families, minimizing income taxation in generational wealth transfers is the primary objective, which mostly involves holding onto appreciated assets until death (with 1031 exchanges in between in many cases) and careful planning of retirement account distributions (which are taxable only when distributed and can be stretched out over one or two lifetimes in many cases and used to fund the smaller charitable gifts that these families make at death in other cases).
A final tool for people who own publicly held company shares (often shares in companies that they or their ancestors founded) is to not have the company distribute dividends or sell the stock. This means that the stock is only subject to corporate level taxes (with profits reinvested to make more profits) rather than facing "double taxation" at both the corporate level and the individual level (which combined, is about twice as high as corporate taxes only).
Transfer Tax Reduction
Up to the estate tax exemption ($13.61 million per lifetime per person in 2024 and inheritable by a surviving spouse), this is easy. This exemption is reduced by lifetime non-exempt gifts made during life and reported on IRS Form 709, with the balance available to use at death and reported on IRS Form 706.
For very affluent people, the key is to leverage this $13.61 million exemption, an ability to make annual gifts of up to $18,000 per donor per donee per year (as of 2024) and unlimited gifts of tuition and health care expenses, in order to pass as much on as possible tax free.
The main strategies for doing this include (but are not limited to):

Making lifetime gifts (knowing that they will have a carry over basis for income tax purposes) in order to shift appreciation in the donated asset from the donor to the beneficiary. Sometimes this involves trusts and/or non-voting or non-controlling shares of a family company. Gifts to trusts used to purchase life insurance premiums whose death benefit will be estate tax free since it is owned by a trust is another common way to do this.

Structure assets so that their estate tax valuation is reduced. This could involve making gifts of minority interests in closely held companies that are less valuable than controlling interests in closely held companies. This could involve subjecting real estate to conservation easements. There are other ways to do this as well. Due to inconsistencies and loopholes in the tax laws, this can make the tax value of assets donatively transferred worth less for tax purposes than they ware worth in the aggregate, if done properly. Another way to do this is to subject a business asset to a buy-sell agreement that fixes its value contractually. Carrying large debts on a balance sheet that aren't burdensome on an operational basis (e.g. because it has favorable payment terms) is another way to use this strategy. Simply finding a low ball appraiser who is credible enough to pass IRS muster also serves this purpose.

Make gifts that are partially charitable and partially to a private beneficiary. There are many permutations of this, but the basic idea is to game the way the IRS values an asset so that the true value of the private beneficiary's share of the asset is greater than the IRS valuation of that asset.

Make large outright gifts to charity, which are tax free. The very wealthy (ca. several tens of millions of dollars of wealth or more) often feel that they have provided sufficiently for family after several million to tens of millions of dollars and once accomplishing that often focus on leaving a charitable legacy (e.g. the Carnegie Libraries, or a large private foundation that can also provide a job, at fair market compensation, to family members).

Defer taxes by leaving them to a surviving spouse, in the hope that the surviving spouse will benefit from more generous tax laws when the surviving spouse dies. This was a good strategy for most of the last three decades.

Give heirs benefits that are so intangible (like connections and hints about business and investment opportunities, or use of the donor's personal use items without transferring those items, or values and educations learned from the older generation) that they don't count as gifts.

Avoid making generation skipping transfers in excess of the generation skipping transfer tax exemption.

Make donative transfers (especially of assets with little appreciation yet) during life rather than at death, because the gift tax rate is effectively about a third lower than the estate tax rate even thought the percentage is the time (because lifetime gifts at taxed on the value of the gift exclusive of taxes, while gifts at death are taxed on the value of the inheritance including the amount that will ultimately go to pay estate taxes).

Distributing retirement assets during life leaving only the after tax amount in the owner's estate, rather than at death, can also reduce aggregate taxation.

Pay transfer taxes over time in an installment payment plan, since the IRS interest rate on installment payment plans of transfer taxes is usually lower than what a wealthy person can earn on their investments if they are professionally managed.


See also this related answer involving transfer tax reduction strategies involving gifts.
Basically, if you are going to pay any transfer taxes, it is usually better to get a carry over basis and so that heirs pay some capital gains taxes, is usually better than paying gift and estate taxes (which are taxed at a higher tax rate).
Realistically, beyond about $40 million of net worth, it is almost impossible to avoid transfer taxes entirely, without making large charitable gifts. But it is often possible to reduce transfer tax payments by a third to a half with decent planning.
Changing Policy
The high estate tax rates through 2001 (with an average estate tax rate in excess of exemptions of 55% excluding "bubble rates" that eliminate the benefits of lower marginal rates for small estates), were justified as serving two purposes at once:

Taxing unrealized capital gains (which make up a very large share of large estates), and

As a tax in lieu of an income tax on beneficiaries at close to the maximum personal income tax rate.


The current 40% estate tax rate effectively serves purpose #2 (as a tax in lieu of income taxes on the beneficiary on the gift or inheritance) but no longer serves purpose #1 (as a tax in lieu of a capital gains tax on unrealized gains).
Also given the many tax loopholes described above, the 40% tax rate nominally, often works out to be 20%-27% of the actual value transferred (a reduction it is hard to achieve with ordinary income, but easy to achieve with many kinds of unearned income in the U.S. tax system).
Revenue Impacts
According to the Congressional Budget Office:

Estate and gift tax revenues in 2020 totaled $17.6 billion, which was
0.5 percent of total receipts and 0.1 percent of GDP. Since 1980, combined estate and gift tax revenues have varied from close to zero
as a share of GDP (or $7 billion) in 2011 to 0.3 percent of GDP (or
$28 billion) in 1999.

Of course, in the rare case of the death of a single, very wealthy billionaire who did little estate planning, this could dramatically impact the total estate tax revenues for the U.S. in that year.
No capital gains taxes are paid on account of death.
Income in respect of decedent (IRD) income taxes on retirement assets (it also applies to other income but is trivial in its share of total IRD revenue) is also a very significant burden on middle class to upper middle class families.
There is no coherent policy justification for the stark distinction made in the tax law between income in respect of a decedent (which is heavily taxed) and capital gains (which is very lightly taxed, if it is taxed at all). This is largely a historical accident and a reflection of differing degrees of political power between the affected potential taxpayers.
Note that The vast majority of wealth transfers through inheritance is of estates less than $13 million going to a non-spouse and non-charity. There are about 2500 taxable estates per year (out of about 3 million deaths per year - one in 1000+ deaths) that transfer an average of about $98 million each. The aggregate amount subject to the estate tax after exemptions is about $44 billion per year (about 1.1% of all inheritances received in a given year by value).
The rest of the estimatd roughly $4,000 billion a year that is inherited in the the U.S. (a highly speculative number that involves some big time value of money and investment return assumptions) is from the other 3 million smaller estates that are below the $13 million cutoff (exclusive of transfers to surviving spouses and charities). The average inheritance is about $46K. The average inheritance in the top 1% is about $719K.
The exclusion of capital gains accrued but not realized at death is estimated by the U.S. Treasury Department to reduce federal income tax revenues by about $27 billion dollars a year.

It should also be in theory impossible to just borrow X amount against
the stock and use that for the tax because the estate tax is charged
on all assets- i.e., anything you borrow to pay the tax is also an
asset and gets taxed.

Law.SE doesn't address what the law should be, but bottom line, Congress has so far disagreed, although some people have argued for this tax reform (mostly Democrats).

You would expect from a capital gains tax on the sale of the
inheritance plus the inheritance tax itself that 90% of this would be
taxed and $5b at most would be left. In reality her net worth is
listed as $15 billion.

In real life, with absolutely no tax planning or estate planning and no charitable gifts or gifts to a surviving spouse, the estate tax on $15 billion is about $6 billion, leaving $9 billion after tax.
If capital gains which taxed at death (which they aren't) the tax bill would increase by about $2.14 billion with no planning (there is an estate tax deduction for income taxes paid) to a total of $8.14 billion leaving about $6.84 billion after taxes.
In reality, the same strategies that reduce estate taxable wealth also tend to reduce balance sheet wealth. Someone with balance sheet wealth of $15 billion ends up paying $6 billion of taxes, but the nominal $9 million left over is really worth $16 billion or so in the long run considering the family as a whole, in a typical case.
Footnote Regarding The Poor Man's Gift and Estate Tax
Lots of working class people and middle class people turn to the Medicaid long term care program to pay for nursing homes and home health care that they can't afford. About half of all people need nursing home care or home health care and almost all of those people who are working class or middle class turn to Medicaid to pay for it.
Gifts made within five years of needing care can disqualify you entirely or for a number of months from the program, which you really need when you need it, functioning as basically a 100% gift tax for affected people. If you can't get the gifts back from the person to whom you gave the money, you will frequently die prematurely because you don't have access to the skilled nursing care that you need to stay alive. I've spent the better part of last year plus litigating a case where that happened involving gifts whose implications were not understood at the time.
Medicaid is structured like a social welfare program but is actually a guaranteed government loan (interest free). Every dime that any part of the Medicaid program pays for you during you life is tallied up and can be recovered as a lien against your property or a claim in your probate estate at death. This is called the Medicaid estate recovery system.
This is effectively wipes out a large share (and often 100%) of the estates of about half of working class and middle class people, eliminating their ability to transfer their limited net worth to the next generation.
I'm oversimplifying a very complicated program in this section, but that's the gist of how it usually plays out.
In the U.S., the share of inherited wealth lost by working class and middle class families to the Medicaid estate recovery system greatly exceeds the share of the wealth of the very affluent lost to transfer taxation, and the raw dollars recovered by the Medicaid estate recovery system are pretty modest.

Estate recovery raises relatively few revenues: $733 million in 2019,
which offset 0.1% of the over $600 billion that Medicaid spent in
2019.

The Medicaid estate recovery system generates about 4% of the revenue of the federal estate tax.
In the 2024 Presidential election, Harris had campaigned to abolish it. Trump did not take a public position on that issue during his Presidential campaign.

Those sound like illegal tax evasion schemes rather than avoidance but I assume that is what they did.

@user77952 All of those approaches are 100% legal and probably 90%-95% of affluent people use some of them. All facts are fully disclosed to the IRS which signs off on it. The illegal options are things like converting your wealth to gold bars, hiding it, and not reporting it on return (a famously failed strategy for one wealthy family trying to avoid Japanese estate taxes), or otherwise omitting or intentionally undervaluing assets. Non-reporting of offshore assets (U.S. estate taxes are on global assets of U.S. persons) is probably the most common illegal method.

The no capital gains if not selling explains why hardly any income tax is paid but from what you wrote the transfer taxes should still amount to significantly larger numbers than the $17 billion you quoted. Total wealth transfer through inheritances is several trillion $ per year in the US, so the tax comes to something like 0.5% on average, not the 20 to 26% you claimed. In other words, I don't think any of the billionaires actually paid 20% inheritance tax on billions worth of assets.

@quarangue The vast majority of wealth transfers through inheritance is of estates less than $13 million going to a non-spouse and non-charity. There are about 2500 taxable estates per year (out of about 3 million deaths per year - one in 1000+ deaths) that transfer an average of about $98 million each. The rest is from smaller estates. https://taxfoundation.org/data/all/federal/estate-tax-returns-data/

You don't mention transfers of assets to trusts managed by chains of shell companies in nations with very forgiving tax policies or simply little enforcement. Given the revelations of the Panama Papers and the Credit Suise leaks this seems like a very common tax avoidance/tax fraud strategy for the very rich.

@CharlesE.Grant This is not a common tax strategy, it can be a questionable legality, and more often than not it doesn't work. Legal means of reducing transfer taxes dwarf this kind of questionable tactic in magnitude. The audit rate is 50%. Getting caught is common. I do mention in a comment to the other answer, however, the fraudulently omitting foreign assets from an estate tax return is probably the most common form of fraud in this area.

@ohwilleke I appreciate that there is an ascertainment bias problem here, but Mossack Fonseca by themselves created 200,000 shell companies, and attracted very high profile clients like the PM of the UK and Iceland. It also seems like it was a very important part of the Credit Suisse business for high net worth individuals. I think the take away of the Credit Suisse leaks, the Panama papers, and now the Pandora papers, was that this is far more common than anyone thought.


You would expect from a capital gains tax on the sale of the inheritance plus the inheritance tax itself that 90% of this would be taxed and $5b at most would be left. In reality her net worth is listed as $15 billion.

Why do you think she sold anything? The inheritance she received is after tax, the tax is on the estate (see this question, and ohwilleke's excellent answer about the US system). There's no "inheritance tax" in the US, and beneficiaries of the estate do not pay tax on their share of the distributions. There are a lot of ways to mitigate some of the estate tax impacts with advance planning, creativity, and well-paid lawyers and accountants.
The rich can access their equity without liquidating the underlying assets similarly to us plebs - using pledged asset lines of credit. For the "poor" people, the main asset would be their home, and the line of credit would be called "HELOC" - Home Equity Line of Credit. But you can pledge shares as well, or any other asset a bank is willing to take as a collateral.
See also the related discussion at money@SE.

You're incorrect. Inheritance tax is always paid when you inherit.

@user77952 you're saying this because that's what you think, or because that's what you want to believe? Because neither is relevant, the reality is what it is.

So when is inheritance tax ever paid? Why don't it subtract from net worth?

@user77952 never. There's no inheritance tax in the US.

@littleadv "There's no "inheritance tax" in the US" Well five U.S. states and all of the county governments in Nebraska have state/local inheritance taxes in addition to the federal one, so that isn't 100% true. Details can be found at: https://www.actec.org/resources-for-wealth-planning-professionals/state-death-tax-chart/ But there are no inheritance taxes on beneficiaries (only federal taxes on the decedent's estate some of which sometimes goes to state, and 3 states with stand alone estate taxes) in the other 44 U.S. states and D.C., except probate fees and court charges in some of them.

People reach enough to pay estate taxes in the U.S. are generally using margin loans against stock or just unsecured lines of credit supported by a balance sheet, rather than HELOCs which are mostly a middle class/upper middle class thing by people who don't face meaningful estate tax liability.

Right, that's what I said

@littleadv Fair. Upon rereading your answer, I see that.
